# Button behaving differently in 6.1 vs. 7.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, rubymotion, ios6.1

I have the following code to show a simple button:

```
button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
button.center = CGPointZero
button.frame = [[container.width/2-button.frame.size.width/2,150], [280,50]]
button.setTitle("Categorize New Project", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
button.addTarget(self, 
                 action: "moveToChildView:",
                 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```

When I run this app in simulator iPhone retina (3.5 inch) with 6.1 it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I run it in simulator iPhone retina with 7.0 it looks like this:

[image]

Does this code need to change to work well with 7.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of iOS 7 the default rounded rectangle button looks like this. See the [UI transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Controls.html). I suggest using custom buttons to prevent such discrepancies between versions.

Comment: Best course of action is UIButtonTypeCustom, as Alexander suggests

Comment: If I set `app.deployment_target` to 6.1 in the Rakefile will the app look ok to the people on ios7?

Comment: @Alexander will you please give sample code here, as i may use wrong code in my project, your sample code may help me to improve my project

Answer (score 1):

As `Alexander` said it is new look of iOS7 and he also suggest to use custom buttons, `which is good advice`, 
But here there is one another way to solve this problem which will give you bellow output
[image]


**Using this code**

```
self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.myButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Thanks If I set `app.deployment_target` to 6.1 in the Rakefile will the app look ok to the people on ios7?